# Redis: How to increment hash key when adding data?

Tags: redis, increment

I'm iterating through data and dumping some to a Redis DB.  Here's an example:

hmset id:1 username "bsmith1" department "accounting"

How can I increment the unique ID on the fly and then use that during the next hmset command?  This seems like an obvious ask but I can't quite find the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use another key, a String, for storing the last ID. Before calling `HMSET`, call `INCR` on that key to obtain the next ID. Wrap the two commands in a `MULTI/EXEC` block or a Lua script to ensure the atomicity of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Like Itamar mentions you can store your index/counter in a separate key. In this example I've chosen the name `index` for that key.

**Python 3**

```
KEY_INDEX = 'index'
r = redis.from_url(host)

def store_user(user):
  r.incr(KEY_INDEX, 1)  # If key doesn't exist it will get created
  index = r.get(KEY_INDEX).decode('utf-8')  # Decode from byte to string
  int_index = int(index)  # Convert from string to int
  result = r.set('user::%d' % int_index, user)
  ...
```

Note that `user::<index>` is an arbitrary key chosen by me. You can use whatever you want.

If you have multiple machines writing to the same DB you probably want to use [`pipelines`](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.Redis.pipeline).